# Using Joda's LocalDate or DateTime in a Class

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm attempting to build a generic `Event` class which models a calendar event.  The event has either a full start date/time, represented by a Joda `DateTime`, or just a start date, represented by a Joda `LocalDate`.

I'd like to make `Event` generic and simplify a lot of the current `if an all-day event then do this otherwise do that` logic scattered throughout the code but can't find a superclass of `DateTime` and `LocalDate` which still contains useful methods to obtain information such as the start date.  Is there some way to do this or do I need to keep my current way of doing things?

Answer (score 0):

What about replacing DateTime + LocalDate with just:

```
org.joda.time.Interval
```

It is essentially a pair of instants which could represent the start/end of any Event.  Should cover 30 minute events, or 5 day events.

Comment: The end result of the processing is an `Interval`, however given that `LocalDate` is not an instant I'm still stuck with the problem of how to handle events which start on the same day regardless of timezone.